# Thinkpad t490 with Ubuntu 18.04 flickering screen

Tags: ubuntu, display, thinkpad

I bought this Thinkpad T490 and installed Ubuntu 18.04. Everything is fine except the screen starts flickering whenever I try to dim the screen with function key (same with F5).

I haven't used the pre-installed Windows 10 on this machine, so I don't know how it is with Windows 10.

Comment: Start the ThinkPad with a bootable USB key to bypass the existing operating system.  Does the screen still flicker?   If not, then find new drivers BIOS, Chipset and then Video for Linux for your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just tried updating software using "Ubuntu Software", and the problem is gone - the updates must have included Video drivers, I guess. @John, if you would like to format your comment as an answer, I could flag it as the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your ThinkPad with a bootable USB key to bypass the existing operating system.

Does the screen still flicker? If not, then find new drivers BIOS, Chipset and then Video for Linux for your machine.

This should solve your problem.